# Linking Assignments to Rubrics in Moodle

Tags: moodle, assign, relation

Rubrics in Moodle are fine but it's hard to get an overview of all the rubrics used in a course.
I'm trying to write a query that lists all the assignments together with their rubric criteria.
This is my query:

```
SELECT cou.fullname, ass.name, def.name, cri.description
FROM mdl_course cou
inner join mdl_assign ass on ass.course = cou.id
inner join mdl_course_modules cmod on cmod.course = cou.id
inner join mdl_context ctx on ctx.instanceid = cmod.id
inner join mdl_grading_areas are on are.contextid = ctx.id
inner join mdl_grading_definitions def on def.areaid = are.id
inner join mdl_gradingform_rubric_criteria cri on cri.definitionid = def.id
where cou.fullname like '%rduin%1%' 
order by cou.fullname, ass.name, cri.sortorder
```

It took me about two hours to find the link between Assignments and their grading_definitions, but the query still generates too many records. I guess I have to add another join or relationship, but can't figure out which.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: there is a double relationship between (assignments and courses) and coursemoudules:
    inner join mdl_course_modules cmod on cmod.course = cou.id and ass.id=cmod.instance